# Can you use an `enum` with an input in GitHub Action's `action.yml` and a workflow file?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a GitHub action (in `.github/actions/my-custom-action`) that takes an input which is an enum. In `action.yml`:

```yaml
inputs:
  my-enum-input:
    description: "This is an input that's an enum"
    default: "all"
    required: true
```

Where `INPUT_MY_ENUM_INPUT` has a type like `['all', 'a', 'b']` that's checked in the script file called by the `action.yml` file. Is there a way to enforce the enum in the `action.yml` file as an input, and check the Worksheet YAML file that calls the action to make sure it's valid?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like [a lot of people wanted this feature](https://github.community/t/can-workflow-dispatch-input-be-option-list/127338/51) and [the GitHub team added it](https://github.community/t/can-workflow-dispatch-input-be-option-list/127338/54). I can't find it anywhere in their docs but it is documented in [their blog post announcing the feature](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-11-10-github-actions-input-types-for-manual-workflows/). If you declare an input variable `name` of type `choice` you can limit the list of input `options` as shown below:

```
inputs:
  name:
    type: choice
    description: Who to greet
    options: 
    - monalisa
    - cschleiden
```

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way for a GitHub Action to take a list/enum as input type, only strings are accepted at this time. There are a bunch of topics on this on the GitHub forums:

- https://github.community/t/can-workflow-dispatch-input-be-option-list/127338
- https://github.community/t/can-action-inputs-be-arrays/16457